# How can I change a button name in windows form c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Im starting to learn c# and Im trying to make a simple app that when I press a button the button's name changes to "Clicked" but I cant make it change the name. This is what I did:

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Text= "Clicked";
    }
```

Comment: Looks like `Button1_Click` is never hit. Put a breakpoint on the line where you change the text. Does the debugger hit it when you click the button? If not, check that you have the event handler hooked up correctly.

Comment: Unless you have an old unfixed version of VS the button is named `button1` and its Click event should be `button1_Click`. You are changing the `Text`, which should work. You can't change the actual name; you could change the `Name` property. So the name, and the `Name` and `Text` properties are 3 (!!!) different things. Confusingly : `Name` != name.

Comment: You can rename the button at design time, but not at runtime. As noted above the Button.Text property is text that is displayed in the button, not the actual name of it. At design time look at the Properties window of the button and check that its Click event (under lightning flash symbol) is set to that in the code behind file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button1_Click event is not assigned to button1 control,  select button then navigate to properties then select events then select Button1_Click at click event then button1 text will change on click.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Text= "Clicked";
}
```

It works that way

Answer (score -1):

The `Text` property is used to set the text caption displayed in the `Button` control. It seems you don't get the event handler triggered at all. Just see a breakpoint and see how it is working under the debugger.

But if you need to change the name of object pointer (button name) you can't really do that after declaring it. You have to set a new object reference instead:

```
Button newButtonName = button1;
```